# How to delete records in another mysql table only if all the matching records have been flagged

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

```
table_a
user_id  canon_id
1       1000
2       1000
3       1000
11      4344
7       2023
8       2023
10      2023
12      3333

table_b
user_id  flag
1        0
2        0
3        1
11       1
7        1
8        1
10       1
12       0
```

In above case, user_ids corresponding to 2023 and 4344 should be deleted but 1000 and 3333 shouldn't because some records are 0. The delete operation should only work on table table_a and keep table_b intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
delete a
    from table_a a join
         (select user_id
          from table_b b
          group by user_id
          having sum(flag <> 1) = 0
         ) bu
         on a.user_id = bu.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `not exists` to delete records from the first table (I called it `a`) for which no other record exists in the other table (called `b`) with the same `user_id` and a `flag` set to `0`:

```
delete from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.user_id = a.user_id and b.flag = 0)
```

Note that this will also delete records in `a` that have no corresponding record in `b`. If you want to avoid that, you need another subquery:

```
delete from a
where 
    not exists (select 1 from b where b.user_id = a.user_id and b.flag = 0)
    and exists (select 1 from b where b.user_id = a.user_id)
```